# How to solve this complex limits at infinity with trig?

Tags: limits

Please consider this limit question

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a\sin\left(\frac{a(x+1)}{2x}\right)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{x\cdot \sin\left(\frac{a}{2x}\right)}$$

How should I solve this? I have no idea where to start please help.

Comment: $x\to \infty $ so $\frac{1}{x} \to 0$, here you can use $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x)/x = 1$

Comment: maybe it could be better use the term difficult instead of complex to avoid initial misunderstanding reading the title, even if it is not difficult at all by standard limits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint is given in the comment box, another hint is that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{a(x+1)}{2x}=\dfrac{a}{2}$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sin\left(\dfrac{a(x+1)}{2x}\right)=\sin\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{a(x+1)}{2x}\right)=\sin\left(\dfrac{a}{2}\right)$.

The fact that one can swipe the limit and the $\sin$ function needs some justification, essentially it is about the continuity of $\sin$ at any point, in this case, it is at the point $a/2$:

$|\sin u-\sin(a/2)|<\epsilon$ for all $|u-a/2|<\delta$, now choose a large $M>0$ such that $\left|\dfrac{a(x+1)}{2x}-\dfrac{a}{2}\right|<\delta$ for all $x\geq M$, then for such an $x$, one has $\left|\sin\left(\dfrac{a(x+1)}{2x}\right)-\sin\left(\dfrac{a}{2}\right)\right|<\epsilon$.

Comment: can I put lim into sin function? I did not realise this..; it is continuous.. :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, one needs to write the $\epsilon$-argument about that, but that is not hard.

Comment: I have edited that, so now it goes through.

Comment: Nice explanation for upper part!

Comment: s//swipe/swap/  :-)

Answer (score 7):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\frac{a\sin\left(\frac{a(x+1)}{2x}\right)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{x\cdot \sin\left(\frac{a}{2x}\right)}=\frac{a\sin\left(\frac{a(x+1)}{2x}\right)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{\frac{a}2\cdot \frac{\sin\left(\frac{a}{2x}\right)}{\frac{a}{2x}}}$$

Comment: personally I find the below hint more intuitive, skipped too much.

Comment: @JoshCorner It is indeed just a hint, note that the "difficult" part is only at the denominator and we can handle that by standard limit, how it is pointed out from user284331, since $a(x+1)/2x \to a/2$ the upper part is trivial.

Comment: @JoshCorner In any case it is not bad receive different hint by different answers for you I guess! Most important that now it is clear to you.

Answer (score 3):

Make life easier using $x=\frac 1 y$.

So the problem reduces to 
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{a\, y}{\sin\left(\frac{a y}{2}\right)} \sin \left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{a}{2}  (y+1)\right) \right)$$ and the first term looks quite familiar.

Comment: Nice alternative trick!

Comment: @gimusi. Thank you ! It is very convenient when you have limits to $\infty$ and still much more when you want to use Taylor series to see how the limit is approached (one of my manias !). Cheers.

Comment: I always do when the limit is not to zero nor infinity (my manias too!)

Answer (score 1):

Trivial with *equivalents*:

as $x\to\infty$,

- $\dfrac{a(x+1)}{2x}\to \dfrac a2$, so $\sin\dfrac{a(x+1)}{2x}\sim_\infty \sin \dfrac a2$,
- $\sin\dfrac{a}{2x}\sim_\infty\dfrac{a}{2x} $,
  so that
  $$\frac{a\sin \dfrac{a(x+1)}{2x}\,\sin\dfrac{a}{2}}{x\cdot \sin \dfrac{a}{2x}}\sim_\infty\frac{a\sin^2\dfrac a2}{x\,\dfrac a{2x}}=2\sin^2\dfrac a2=1-\cos a.$$

Comment: I don't understand why sin(a/2x) just becomes sin(a/2x)

Comment: Why $\sin(a/2x) $ becomes the same? Where?

Comment: sorry I meant a/2x.

Comment: @JoshCorner - $f(x) \sim_a g(x)$ if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)/g(x) = 1$. That equivalence follows from $a/2x \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ and $\frac {\sin x}x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a\color{#f00}{\sin(\frac{a(x+1)}{2x})}\cdot \sin(\frac{a}{2})}{\color{#00ff}{x\cdot \sin(\frac{a}{2x})}}\tag{1}$$

$\color{#f00}{\sin\left(\frac{a(x+1)}{2x}\right)} = \sin\left(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{a}{2x}\right);\quad$ so $x \to \infty \implies \sin\left(\frac{a}{2}+0\right) = \sin\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)$

L'Hopital: 
$\color{#00ff}{x\sin\left(\frac{a}{2x}\right)} = \left(\frac{\sin \left(\frac{a}{2x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}\right) =\left(\frac{-\frac{a\cos \left(\frac{a}{2x}\right)}{2x^2}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)=\left(\frac{a}{2}\cos \left(\frac{a}{2x}\right)\right);\quad$ so $x \to \infty \implies\frac{a}{2}\cos(0) = \frac{a}{2}$

$$\frac{a\color{#f00}{\sin\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}\cdot \sin(\frac{a}{2})}{\color{#00ff}{\frac{a}{2}}}\tag{2}$$
$$2\sin ^2\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\tag{3}$$

> $$1-\cos\left(a\right)\tag{3}$$

Comment: In my opinion l'Hopital should be avoided when we can simply refer to standard limits.

Comment: @gimusi Unless you can show a discontinuity or other feature at which L'Hopital does not apply,  why not use a valuable theorem?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It of course a valuable theorem which is needed also to proof Taylor's theorem but I do not consider that a good tool to solve limit since it acts as a black box machine and it doesn't give any enlightments about the role that each term plays in the to determine the limit. For that, I always suggest when possible to use standard limits for simple limits and Taylor's expansion for limits of higher order. In some cases l'Hopital can be very useful and effective, as for example for limit which involve integral functions.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Of course it is a my own personal opinion and suggestion based on my small experience and it is mainly motivated by an educational issue. Standard limits and Taylor's expansion give a better feeling of the role played by each term in the expression. That's all, nothing personal with l'Hopital!